# Android Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS resulting in crash

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am using the following line of code to redirect user to location settings screen

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), 0);
```

It works fine on most devices, but crashes on some Samsung devices with an exception :

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle
>   Intent { act=android.settings.LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS }

Is there a better way to handle location settings ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a better way to handle location settings ?

Pretty much all those action strings on the `Settings` class mention in the JavaDocs that the activity may not exist and so you should handle that appropriately (e.g., wrap your `startActivity()` call in a `ActivityNotFoundException` handler).

In this case, there isn't an obvious fallback option other than `ACTION_SETTINGS`. You might display a `Snackbar` or dialog from the exception handler indicating that this device does not have direct third-party access to the location settings screen.

Also note that `startActivityForResult()` is useless in your situation; just use `startActivity()`.

Comment: Thanks. I just realized that I have not handled ActivityNotFoundException anywhere in my app while using system provided activities; will do a thorough review now :)

Comment: Is it possible to take the user to the exact app for location permissions?  Or does it have to be the entire Location settings screen for all apps on the device.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: Location *permissions*, like `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`, are handled through standard runtime permissions on Android 6.0+. Whether location is *enabled* or not usually is a device-wide setting. Use the `Intent` action from the question to lead the user there, with a `try`/`catch` block in case the manufacturer did not include support for that `Intent` action.